# Update not working properly

Tags: linux-mint

Whenever I write sudo apt-get update it does not work properly and shows following :

```
tusharmakkar08@tusharmakkar08-Satellite-C660 ~ $ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia Release.gpg                                
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org nadia Release.gpg                            
Ign http://archive.canonical.com nadia Release.gpg                             
Get:1 http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia Release.gpg [197 B]                  
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security Release.gpg                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg                               
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates Release.gpg                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release.gpg                           
Get:2 http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia Release [17.6 kB]                    
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg [933 B]          
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release                                   
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org quantal Release.gpg                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                              
Ign http://archive.canonical.com nadia Release                                 
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security Release                          
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources                              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release                               
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release [49.6 kB]            
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg [933 B]            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org nadia Release                                
Get:6 http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/main i386 Packages [22.6 kB]         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org quantal Release                              
Get:7 http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/upstream i386 Packages [11.3 kB]     
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner i386 Packages                 
Get:8 http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/import i386 Packages [44.0 kB]       
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia Release                                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates Release                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release                                  
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release [49.6 kB]              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_IN                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en                       
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages [104 kB] 
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org quantal/free i386 Packages                   
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org quantal/non-free i386 Packages               
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                         
Err http://archive.canonical.com nadia/partner i386 Packages                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://archive.canonical.com nadia/partner Translation-en_IN               
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                         
Ign http://archive.canonical.com nadia/partner Translation-en                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-en_IN             
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted i386 Packages [3,531 B]
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-en                
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe i386 Packages [45.8 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1,402 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages                       
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/import Translation-en_IN               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted i386 Packages                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse i386 Packages                 
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/import Translation-en                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en        
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/main Translation-en_IN                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en                      
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/main Translation-en                    
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/upstream Translation-en_IN             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en                
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/upstream Translation-en                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en                  
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages [225 kB]   
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages [4,841 B]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages [179 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [10.8 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en          
Err http://packages.medibuntu.org nadia/free i386 Packages                     
  404  Not Found
Err http://packages.medibuntu.org nadia/non-free i386 Packages                 
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security/main i386 Packages               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org nadia/free Translation-en_IN                 
Err http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security/restricted i386 Packages         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security/universe i386 Packages           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org nadia/free Translation-en                    
Err http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security/multiverse i386 Packages         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security/main Translation-en_IN           
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org nadia/non-free Translation-en_IN             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security/multiverse Translation-en_IN     
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org nadia/non-free Translation-en                
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security/restricted Translation-en_IN     
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org quantal/free Translation-en_IN               
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security/universe Translation-en_IN       
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com nadia-security/universe Translation-en          
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en_IN         
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en_IN   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en_IN   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en_IN     
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org quantal/free Translation-en                  
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org quantal/non-free Translation-en_IN           
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org quantal/non-free Translation-en              
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia/main i386 Packages 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com nadia-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
Fetched 771 kB in 1min 19s (9,715 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/nadia/free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/nadia/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My Sources.list looks like :

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ nadia main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ nadia main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ nadia-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ nadia-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ nadia partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ nadia free non-free

# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb apps
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb games
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ quantal partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ quantal free non-free

# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb apps
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb games
```

Comment: Care to post your sources.list?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing OSes.

Comment: Now what can I do to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nadia` is for LinuxMint only. Change to `quantal`.

E.g.:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ nadia partner
# to
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ quantal partner
```

Keep `nadia` for:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

---

Files:

```
ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Check:

```
inxi -r
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked .. After this one may need to comment out duplicate portions in the sources.list by commenting the duplicate sources :)

Comment: What does inix -r do  ? It is showing command not found in my computer.

Comment: It shows distro repository data. `apt-cache search inxi`

Comment: Please edit in your answer inix -r to inxi -r .. I am not able to do so . I hope this is what you wanted to write .

Comment: @TusharMakkar: Ah. Thanks! And sorry about that.